# Modifying a field to nullable is running forever

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When I try to change a field to accept null values the command never ends. It is strange because another similar command is executed without problem.

```
ALTER TABLE "MYTABLE" MODIFY ("A" NULL); -- ok
ALTER TABLE "MYTABLE" MODIFY ("B" NULL); -- runs forever (freezed?)
```

- "A" and "B" have the same structure: "NUMBER(1)", DEFAULT 0, NOT NULL, CHECK(in (0, 1)). Also both have indexes.
- The table "MYTABLE" has 100M records.
- There are no accesses being made to the database at the moment (no parallel queries or others locks).
- I am using Oracle 11g.

I think that change a field to accept null values should be a quick task. I don't know why is running forever and just in one field. Does anyone know what might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to check what is the session doing e.g. in `V$SESSION`.

Comment: Additionally thing about, why do you want the column to be nullable if you set the `DEFAULT 0`

Comment: Bad choices in life. This field must be nullable now. The default will be removed soon, but the software is not handling this yet.